# Understanding ES6 Modules import/export

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bundle, es6-modules

I'm starting learn ES6 modules and `import`/`export` syntax and I want that my modules are executed only where they are needed.

I created two simple modules that connect to a `<div>` with a particular `class` or `id` to run.

For example:

```
// product.js

import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue';

export default function() {

  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#c-product',
    data: {
      counter: 0,
    },
    methods: {
      addToCart: function() {
        this.counter++;
      },
      removeFromCart: function() {
        this.counter--;
      }
    }
  });

}
```

Then I have the other module for a carousel:

```
// carousel.js

import Glide from '@glidejs/glide';

export default function() {

  new Glide('.glide', {
    type: 'carousel',
    startAt: 0,
    perView: 3,
    breakpoints: {
      800: {
        perView: 2
      }
    }
  }).mount();

};
```

Then I bundle everything with Gulp + Browserify in order to have a `main.js` file where I import and execute the modules:

```
// main.js
import Product from './product';
import Carousel from './carousel';

Product();
Carousel();
```

Now I have my `main.js` file and I'm ready to insert it into the `.html` pages, but I have errors in console depending on whether those divs exist in page or not.

Example: if in `product.html` page there are no carousels, I have errors in console regarding missing the `<div>` with the carousel class.

Hope to be clear.

Can you help me understand?

[Here the example on product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv85l.png)

Comment: What are your errors?

Comment: I've added an image.

Comment: The error states that the root element (with id c-product) must exist. Here's a crazy idea - did you check that the element exists in the dom?

Comment: @Kaspars `#c-product` exists, in fact the error is not on the carousel. 
But my question is: Do I have to instance my module not into `main.js`?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with modules. Or are you looking to create different scripts for different pages, that import only the modules that are needed on that specific page?

Comment: @Bergi the second one. Thanks. Sorry I'm a newbie. :-)

Comment: Yeah, you wouldn't create a `main.js` then that is included in every page. In the product.html that doesn't have carousels, you'd only embed a `<script type=module>import Product from './product.js'; Product();</script>` and not load the `carousel.js` that you don't need (and which doesn't work on that page).

Comment: @Bergi So, the `main.js` is only for importing? Do I have to manage my modules in every page into the html? It looks like an old way. But if so, okay.

Comment: Yes, the main.js code is only for importing and initialising. And yes, you'll want to manage your modules if you want to load them individually in different pages. Or, as outlined in the answer below, fix the modules so that they work (but might not do anything) on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with a bit of defensive coding. Each of your modules depend on a certain DOM node being present, so you should query for the element before instantiating the module. Like:

```
// product.js

import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue';

export default function() {
  var vueRoot = document.getElementById('c-product')
  if (!vueRoot) return;  // element does not exist, so we return before instantiating

  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#c-product',
    data: {
      counter: 0,
    },
    methods: {
      addToCart: function() {
        this.counter++;
      },
      removeFromCart: function() {
        this.counter--;
      }
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: Initially I thought of something like that, but then it means that I have to do an `if` for every module I create? Is it possible that there is not an "official" solution?

Comment: Indeed.. if your module depend on a specific element, you need to check for it

Comment: Maybe the question is: Where do I have to invoke the modules? In `main.js`? If so, then it is right that it has global errors. So the `main.js` is only for importing?

Comment: Well, there is not a single answer to that - it's a matter of architecture. Using a main.js file to import global modules is certainly one way to go - but you could also build specific bundles for individual pages (and avoid loading ie. VueJS on pages that dont need it)

Comment: Oh, and based on the error you are getting, I am guessing that your main.js file is loaded in the `head` tag - or at least before document ready. That wont fly.. in that case it is not possible to query the document, and the modules will always fail. It's good practice to load JS as the last thing in `body`

Comment: Nope. Is loaded as the last thing in `<body>`.